# Como visualizo as publicações que negativei?

Tags: suporte, votos

Gostaria de revisar as publicações que negativei para remover (ou dar *upvote*) nas que foram editadas, apresentando melhorias - acho que nada mais justo. Mas não lembro como faço para ver isso...

Lembro-me de já ter acessado algo parecido há um tempo, mas não me recordo como foi feito. É no próprio StackOverflow ou naquele site que é preciso montar *queries* para acessar informações do SOpt?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No seu perfil, na metade de baixo, a última aba lista os votos, e lá você pode filtrar para ver somente os votos contra. Exemplo (do meu próprio perfil, já que ninguém vê essa aba no perfil dos outros):

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

[Link direto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4808/renan?tab=votes&sort=downvote) (só funciona pra você).

Detalhe: nessa lista não aparecem conteúdos removidos, acho.

Comment: É isso mesmo, obrigado. Saberia me dizer se existe limite diário quando trata-se de remover votos? Sei que para votar existe.

Comment: Não sei, mas se você pretende reverter uma batelada de votos, talvez a gente descubra :)